# Safari on Mac OS X Cache lasts after 'Empty Cache'

Tags: macos, safari, browser-cache

So, I broke a website with some server changes oops. I roll back the changes I made, hit cmd-R, and oh noes, it is still broken. But I relax thinking, there must be something held in safari's cache so I press the handy 'Empty Cache' button. Hit cmd-R for refresh it is still broken. I'm really worried that I've done it and broken something bigtime. But first decide to check on a hand win xp computer, and voila it works.

So the question is how do you "really" clear the cache w/o restart safari, I have many browser windows open a restart every time I make a server side change will ruin me.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!